# Update statement is giving error for table alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I am unable to figure out what is wrong with the following syntax.

```
alter table #table1 add C21 datetime
update #table1 a
set a.C21 = b.C21_result_lab from #table2 b where a.person_id = b.person_id and 
a.source_id = b.source_id
```

Error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 363
>   Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
alter table #table1 add C21 datetime;
update a
set a.C21 = (
  select b.C21_result_lab from #table2 b 
  where 
    a.person_id = b.person_id 
    and 
    a.source_id = b.source_id
)
from #table1 a
```

You must make sure that the select query does not return more than 1 rows.
Or you can do it with a join:

```
update a
set a.C21 = b.C21_result_lab 
from #table1 a inner join #table2 b 
on a.person_id = b.person_id and a.source_id = b.source_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works!

```
alter table #table1 add C21 datetime
update #table1
set C21 = (
    select b.C21_result_lab
    from #table2 b
    where #table1.person_id = b.person_id and #table1.source_id = b.source_id
);
```